# Print numbers divisible by prime numbers in Python

Tags: python

I want to create a function that print numbers from a list in this order:

-numbers divisible by 0 and 1

-numbers divisible by prime numbers (all numbers divisble by 2,then numbers divisible by 3,etc.)

I have two functions earlier in my code. Basic "max" function and "prime_numbers" function that prints prime numbers up to given number, e.g. prime_numbers (50). Both are working fine.

This is the part of my function I have problems with:

```
if max(x) >= 2: 
    divisors = prime_numbers(maks(x)) 
    for i in divisors:
        sel = [x % i == 0 for x in i]
        result.append([i for i in sequence if sequence in sel])
        sequence = [i for i in sequence if i not in sequence]
```

For loop is a mess. What I want to do is the thing I did when writing same function in R.

```
sel <- !as.logical(sequence %% i) 
result <- c(result,sequence[sel]) 
sequence <- sequence[!sel]
```

'Sequence' is already declared in the code and it contains numbers from the list that are bigger or equal to 2.
'Result' is also declared and it contains numbers smaller than 2.

I want to iterate over divisors (prime_numbers) and:

- "sel" contains logical answers whether the number is divisible by a given divisor
- I want to append numbers from "sequence" that are divisible (TRUE value in sel) to previous "result" variable.
- I want to remove numbers that are divisible and already appended to "result" from "sequence" so I can iterate over another divisor.

I'm much more familiar with R than Python and it was easier there. I tried to do something with list comprehensions, but I don't understand it as good.

Comment: "numbers divisible by 0 and 1"... good luck.

Comment: Yeah, OP you should realize 0 will be undefined and 1... well what number isn't divisible by 1!?

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to write simply '0 and 1'. It doesn't have en effect on the code as I'm not iterating over 0 anyway.

Comment: that's really unclear (passing the two comments up there that, i must admit, made me laugh). 
And it's not really clear what your want ? like would it be easier in a dict like ```values['divisor'] = ['a_number', 'another_number'...]```.
And ```[i for i in sequence if i not in sequence]```, well i'm pretty sure it's always empty :).

Comment: Should maybe start by clarifying some of your variables more clearly. Do you want the output to be a sub-list of your initial starting list? So, say you have a list of numbers called 'x', do you want the function to first print a list of all the numbers in x that are divisible by 0 (which will always return an empty list of course!), then a list of all the numbers in x that are divisible by 1 (which will return a list identical to x), then a list of all numbers in x divisible by 2, then 3, then 5 etc etc. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What i want? Let's say I have a list from 0 to 10. I want the result look like that: 0,1,2,4,6,8,10,3,6,9,5,7

Comment: Ah ok I understand now, that makes sense

Comment: edited my answer below as you answer in a clearer way what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick :

```
# result and sequence are defined higher
# and are lists
if max(x) >= 2: 
    divisors = prime_numbers(maks(x)) 
    for i in divisors:
        result += [x for x in sequence if x % i == 0]
```

As your answered comment I edited my answer and this should do the work

Comment: It's really close to what I want, but 'result' is already declared and it contains 0 and/or 1 if they're present in the code, so I have to append it.